# Django creating wrong type for fields in intermediate table (manytomany)

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have a model in Django which the `pk` is not an integer and it has a field which is a `manytomany`. This `manytomany` references the model itself.

When I ran `makemigration` I didn't realize, but it did not create the fields in the intermediate table as `char(N)`. In fact, it create as an `integer`.

```
# models.py
class Inventory(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

This throws errors whenever I try to add objects to my parent model

```
>>> p = Inventory.objects.get(sample_id='sample01')
>>> child = Inventory.objects.get(sample_id='sample02')
>>> p.parent_id.add(child)
```

I get the error

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "sample02"
LINE 1: ...HERE ("inventory_parent_id"."to_inventory_id" IN ('sample...
```

I saw the fields in the intermediate table, `inventory_parent_id`, created by Django and their types are not correct.

```
Columns (3)
|--id (integer)
|--from_inventory_id (integer)
|--to_inventory_id (integer)
```

**My questions are**: Is it bad if I change the types manually? Will it break the migrations? Or did I have to do something so Django can catch this misleading type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to re-create migrations (unapply migrations by using `./manage.py migrate YOURAPP PREVIOUS_MIGRATION_NUMBER` or `./manage.py migrate YOURAPP zero` if it's initial migration), remove migration file (don't forget about `.pyc` file) and generate it again.

If that doesn't help, you can try to create custom through table with proper migration fields and then recreate that migration.

Comment: I think I know where the problem is coming from. I first created the field `manytomany` and ran `makemigrations` + `migrate`. Then, I changed the pk of the field to a char field and Django did not recognize the change to the intermediate table. I will fake migration to the two previous one and try again.

Comment: Even though the answer is not quite what I needed to do I marked as accepted. It happened exactly as my previous comment. I fake the migration to two previous one, create a migration for the changing of pk, then created another migration changing the field to manytomany. I couldn't make it in one migration because it was complaining about the field id could not be removed...